# Office365: Sending a message using SMTP and keeping a copy on the server

Tags: email, smtp, office365, smtpclient

I am sending emails using the .NET SmtpClient via Office 365.

The emails are sent without problem, however the messages are not later shown in sent items.

Is there a way to configure either O365 or SmtpClient to retain a copy of any message sent through SMTP in the mailbox?

Martin.

Answer (score 1):

the Exchange Web Services Managed API might solve your issue. There's a method named SendAndSaveCopy() - shown in the below sample:

```
private void sendEmail()   
{   
    ExchangeService myservice = new ExchangeService();   
    myservice.AutodiscoverUrl("name@domain.com");   

    EmailMessage mymessage = new EmailMessage(myservice);   
    mymessage.Subject = "mysubject";   
    mymessage.Body = "mybody";   
    mymessage.ToRecipients.Add("myrecipient");   
    mymessage.Save();   

    mymessage.SendAndSaveCopy();      
}
```

You can get the Exchange Web Services Managed API here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt674770.aspx

Please also find an example how to use den Exchange Web Services Managed API here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Send-Email-with-Exchange-50189e57

Please let me know if this works for you.

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: Looks great, though maybe I am missing something but there does not seem to be any authentication taking place (nor is there in the example code you referenced). I need to be able to call this from a Windows service so I assume that there is something else I need to do first?